# Is the typical female porn star a big-boobed blonde?

Tags: physiology, pornography

Common opinion seems to believe that the most popular female porn stars are blonds with big boobs.

For example, [this site](http://listverse.com/2010/06/20/top-10-most-famous-adult-film-stars/) from 2010 has Jenna Jameson as the most popular and she fits the description. So is the stereotype true?

PS I know that the internet is awash with stories about this right now (feb 2013) but I couldn't resist posing the question so the answer can be recorded here. I'm happy if someone else posts the definitive answer before I do.

Comment: It's so that it's [legal in Australia](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15790/did-australia-ban-small-breasts-pornography)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From http://venturebeat.com/2013/02/18/the-big-data-of-porn-what-number-crunching-teaches-us-about-adult-films/ (original source is this study: http://jonmillward.com/blog/studies/deep-inside-a-study-of-10000-porn-stars/)

> Based on his review of about 8.6 percent of the database’s profiles, the average porn star has a bra cup size of 34B. Double-D bra sizes were fourth, behind B, C, and D. The most common set of measurements for women was 34-24-34.
>
> And dark-haired porn stars outnumbered blondes by two to one.

The study was based on

> The porn industry never got such penetrating look as in a report today by blogger Jon Millward, who reviewed data from more than 10,000 profiles of porn stars in the Internet Adult Film Database. The result is the big data of porn, a set of facts that would surprise you and your perceptions about sex films on the Internet.

Please note that I'm somewhat skeptical of the findings based on "review of about 8.6 percent of the database’s profiles". There's plenty of data NOT reviewed, unless he fully randomized the profiles to obtain true sampling (the story didn't say).

Comment: Great answer. I note that natural blondes are around 5% of North American population, so blondes are over-represented in the industry.

Comment: Good summary. The only improvement would be to go the Millard's original article and quote some more of his research.

Comment: I also note that he didn't normalize by amount of work.

Comment: Over 10,000 profiles is a ridiculously huge sample size. You can make significant estimates with far far far less data. There are many other ways he could of screwed up his analysis but sample size is not one.

Comment: IOW porn stars differ as much as the general population, with a tendency towards the beauty ideal of the target population. Which of course isn't surprising, as that's what you'd expect of the interests of the customers as well as available employees.

Comment: Was kind of hoping, for the sake of humor, this would have been government grant-funded research, instead of a blogger doing it.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - I trust a blogger over government funded researcher, assuming I have access to data and methodology. At least a blogger doesn't have to play internal politics AND grant politics.

Comment: I would be more interested in the case they'd build to try and justify what they would be doing.  :D